# MVC 2 App - Setting Dynamic Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, dynamic, master-pages, global-asax

I want to be able to set a master page depending on the URL at the time in an MVC 2 application.

I've inserted C# code in my Views and I've gotten this far -

```
<script language="C#" runat="server">
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var hostName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.ToString();
        if (hostName == "localhost")
        {
            this.MasterPageFile = "~/Views/Shared/Site.Master";
        }
        else
        {
            this.MasterPageFile = "~/Views/Shared/Administrator.Master";
        }
    }
</script>
```

The IF statement above was for testing, in reality I'll be pulling the master page names from a database but that will be fine.

If possible, I would obviously rather not inserting the code above onto each and every view. Is it possible to set this from the global.asax file or similar?